# Order the duplicates in my pandas Data frame by adding another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I need to order duplicates in my data frame with a counter value of 1, 2 , 3 etc. The input data frame is like below:

```
         Key    Amount
         xyz     1000
         xyz1    870
         xyz2    1000
         xyz3    1000
         xyz4    650
```

and expected output as

```
         Key    Amount  Duplicate_order
         xyz     1000    1
         xyz1    870     1
         xyz2    1000    2
         xyz3    1000    3
         xyz4    650     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`cumcount`**

```
df['duplicate_order'] = df.groupby('Amount').cumcount()+1

    Key  Amount  duplicate_order
0   xyz    1000                1
1  xyz1     870                1
2  xyz2    1000                2
3  xyz3    1000                3
4  xyz4     650                1
```